# Periodically start a build on a specific node in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I would like to run certain Jenkins builds under different OS-s at a given time and I'm trying to figure out how I can achieve this. If, for example, all my nodes are running Linux and I have a Windows node which turns on at 2 a.m., I'd like to be able to run the build on that node to check if things work as expected under that OS. I don't want to have separate Jenkins jobs for the different OS-s. Is this possible?

I can't seem to be able to find any available plugin or article on the subject. I'm probably not articulating it well enough in my search, but I'm also not quite sure if it's possible (unless you create a copy of the job and tie it to a specific node).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way remote copying jenkins jobs(/Jobs/*_config.xml) between different OS-s,

Jenkins will understand that was local to specific OS and execute them as per trigger setup, try find out remote copy plugins or use scp or pscp commands.

Comment: Please, use just one answer, as this is the way Stackoverflow answers should be like. I've also edited my answer, as I don't think I was clear enough.

Comment: OK,my answer was very simple copy(or sync) /jobs/JOB_NAME/config.xml and make sure config.xml node property is set windows in config.xml (search and replace).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Jenkins jobs are sync between two different OS.(copying job folder), you can establish .xml file sync between two different OS's.

Jenkins jobs are platform independent as per my knowledge you can copy configurations between UNIX to windows and vice versa.

```
JENKINS_HOME
         +- jobs ----(need to get sync)
         +- [JOBNAME]      (sub directory for each job)    
             +- config.xml     (job configuration file)
             +- workspace      (working directory for the version control system)
             +- latest         (symbolic link to the last successful build)
             +- builds
                 +- [BUILD_ID]     (for each build)
                     +- build.xml      (build result summary)
                     +- log            (log file)
                     +- changelog.xml  (change log)
```